# Redirect URL to another domain with same path in Ghost CMS redirects.json

Tags: json, redirect, ghost-blog

I try to use Redirect.json for redirect URLs in ghost CMS.
I use this in redirect.json file

```
[{
        "from": "/([a-zA-Z\d.-]+)",
        "to": "https://blog.anotherdomain.com/$1",
        "permanent": true
}]
```

its redirect to another domain but in URL its printing $1 its unable to fetch URL path
please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

I found the issue with your redirect!
issue missing trailing "/" and unescaped slash

#### from

```
/([a-zA-Z\d.-]+)
```

[missing slash and unescaped slash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUCeB.png)

#### to

```
/([a-zA-Z\\d.-]+)/
```

[fixed version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUCZr.png)

### full copy and paste

```
[{
    "from": "/([a-zA-Z\\d.-]+)/",
    "to": "https://blog.anotherdomain.com/$1",
    "permanent": true
}]
```

## Reference for future people

Go to `/ghost/#/settings/labs`
then click on upload redirects.json

[photo showing the location of the upload redirects button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtVnQ.png)

modify the following code to match your blog

```
[{
    "from": "/([a-zA-Z\\d.-]+)/",
    "to": "https://<YOUR_GOES_HERE>.com/$1",
    "permanent": true
}]
```

## More information on ghost redirects

https://ghost.org/docs/tutorials/creating-content-collections/

Answer (score 0):

@wisemonkey's answer is completely correct (and worked for me as well), but incomplete. You'll also need to add

```
{
    "from": "/",
    "to": "https://<YOUR_GOES_HERE>.com/",
    "permanent": true
}
```

... to redirect the homepage, which isn't caught in the first regex. So the final `redirects.json` file will look like:

```
[{
    "from": "/([a-zA-Z\\d.-]+)/",
    "to": "https://<YOUR_GOES_HERE>.com/$1",
    "permanent": true
},
{
    "from": "/",
    "to": "https://<YOUR_GOES_HERE>.com/",
    "permanent": true
}]
```